# sap.ui.table.Table with visibleRowCountMode="Auto" doesn't adjust its height dynamically in VBox

Tags: css, sapui5

I tried to fit my `sap.ui.table.Table` into a `sap.f.DynamicPage` but the table height won't dynamically resize to the available space in the page content.

I tried to implement the `sap.m.VBox` with the table attribute `visibleRowCountMode="Auto"` to fix this problem but the table height is just fixed to the `minAutoRowCount` parameter of the table.

[image: Screenshot of Table in VBox with minAutoRowCount = 10]

Here is the code snippet of the table inside the page content:

```xml
<f:content>
  <VBox fitContainer="true">
    <OverflowToolbar>
      <!-- ... -->
    </OverflowToolbar>
    <table:Table visibleRowCountMode="Auto"
      minAutoRowCount="10"
      noData="{i18n>noDataText}"
      width="auto">
      <!-- ... -->
    </table:Table>
  </VBox>
</f:content>
```

Any suggestions how the height of the table is resized, for example, if the page header is collapsed / expanded?

SAPUI5 Version: 1.60.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sap.ui.table.Table: visibleRowCountMode="Auto" not working with VBox (FlexBox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66662597/sap-ui-table-table-visiblerowcountmode-auto-not-working-with-vbox-flexbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: adding FlexItemData growFactor worked for my smarttable.

use property

```
visibleRowCountMode="Auto"
```

Update

```
            <layoutData>
                <FlexItemData growFactor="1" baseSize="0%"/>
            </layoutData>
```

table:

```
<Table id="DynamicTableId" selectionMode="MultiToggle" visibleRowCountMode="Auto" minAutoRowCount="10" noData="{i18n>noDataText}"
            fixedColumnCount="1" showColumnVisibilityMenu="true" modelContextChange="onModelContextChange" width="auto">
                <layoutData>
                    <FlexItemData growFactor="1" baseSize="0%"/>
                </layoutData>
</Table>
```

regards

Comment: Hey thanks for your awnser, forgot to say it in the post. The visibleRowCountMode "Auto" doesnt work with the VBox i think, so thats why i said the table only takes half of the available sapce. Gonna Update my Post by this Aspect. Any other suggestions?