# sap.ui.table.Table: visibleRowCountMode="Auto" not working with VBox (FlexBox)

Tags: css, sapui5

I would like the number rows of my `sap.ui.table.Table` to fit the screen height. I tried using `visibleRowCountMode="Auto"` for that but in the beginning, it did not work because certain parent elements did not have a `height="100%"`.

My table is nested quite deeply into several `Page`s and `FlexBox`es but this is kind of how my views look.

```xml
<VBox height="100%" class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin">
  <layout:Splitter id="CSL_idSplitter" height="100%" resize=".onSplitterResize">
    <VBox height="100%">
      <HBox justifyContent="SpaceBetween" height="100%">
        <VBox height="100%">
          <table:Table id="idTable" visibleRowCountMode="Auto" />
          <Button />
        </VBox>
      </HBox>
    </VBox>
  </layout:Splitter>
</VBox>
```

I also added this to my CSS file:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

According to other questions, this seemed to be the solution but it did not work for me. I found out that, in the DOM, the direct parent `<div>` of the table-control (which is automatically created by UI5 and does not seem to belong to any element declared in the view) was the problem because it did not have a style `height: 100%`.

Here is the DOM from the Chrome Dev-Tools (Yellow is my table and in red is the div without any height):

[image]

If I add the height to the element manually, the `visibleRowCountMode="Auto"` works fine.

So I found a quite ugly workaround and I was hoping that anyone would know a nicer way to overcome this issue. When the `View` is loaded, I select the parent `<div>` element of the table and set its height programmatically in `onAfterRendering` of the controller.

```js
onAfterRendering: function() {
  const oTable = this.byId("idTable");
  const oHTMLElement = document.getElementById(oTable.getIdForLabel());
  oHTMLElement.parentNode.style.height = "100%";  
}
```

Since this is just a workaround, I was wondering where the real problem was lying and if anyone could help me solve it.

Comment: I think this is the result of using the Flexbox HBoxs & Vboxs. Setting the height of the parent seems fine to me, another way would be to cut down on you Vbox & HBox usage and use alternative layout elements if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table has sibling controls, a prerequisite for the `visibleRowCountMode="Auto"` or `sap.ui.table.rowmodes.Auto` to work is that the table is allowed to grow within a flexbox element (e.g. `sap.m.VBox`). This can be achieved by adding `<FlexItemData growFactor="1" />` to the `layoutData` aggregation of the table.

```xml
<VBox xmlns="sap.m" renderType="Bare" fitContainer="true"><!-- or height="100%" -->
  <table:Table xmlns:table="sap.ui.table" visibleRowCountMode="Auto">
  <!-- visibleRowCountMode deprecated since 1.119 -->
  <!-- Add sap.ui.table.rowmodes.Auto to the aggregation rowMode instead. -->
    <table:rowMode><!-- since UI5 1.119 -->
      <rowmodes:Auto xmlns:rowmodes="sap.ui.table.rowmodes" />
    </table:rowMode>
    <table:layoutData><!-- Every control has the aggregation layoutData -->
      <FlexItemData growFactor="1" /><!-- Allow the Table to grow -->
    </table:layoutData>
    <table:columns>
      <!-- ... -->
    </table:columns>
  </table:Table>
  <Button /><!-- Other flex box sibling items ... -->
</VBox>
```

From the [API reference of `sap.ui.table.rowmodes.Auto`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.table.rowmodes.Auto):
<sup>Similar description in the old [`visibleRowCountMode="Auto"`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.table.Table#methods/setVisibleRowCountMode)</sup>

> The table must be rendered without siblings in the DOM. The only exception is if the table's parent element is a flexbox, and the table is a flex item allowed to grow and shrink.

Here is a little demo:

```js
globalThis.onUI5Init = () => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView",
  "sap/ui/model/odata/v4/ODataModel",
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
], async (XMLView, ODataModel, JSONModel) => {
  "use strict";
  
  const control = await XMLView.create({
    definition: `<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
      xmlns="sap.m"
      xmlns:table="sap.ui.table"
      displayBlock="true"
      height="100%"
    >
      <App autoFocus="false">
        <Page showHeader="false">
          <VBox
            fitContainer="true" 
            renderType="Bare"
          >
            <ToggleButton
              pressed="{viewModel>/grow}"
              text="{= %{viewModel>/grow} ? '' : 'Enable '}Growing Automatically"
              type="Neutral"
            />
            <table:Table xmlns:table="sap.ui.table"
              class="sapUiSizeCondensed"
              columnHeaderVisible="false"
              selectionMode="None"
              visibleRowCountMode="Auto"
              enableBusyIndicator="true"
              rows="{/People}"
            >
              <table:layoutData>
                <FlexItemData id="myFlexItemData"
                  growFactor="{= %{viewModel>/grow} ? 1 : 0}"
                  backgroundDesign="Solid"
                />
              </table:layoutData>
              <table:rowMode><!-- since UI5 1.119 -->
                <rowmodes:Auto
                  xmlns:rowmodes="sap.ui.table.rowmodes"
                  minRowCount="3"
                />
              </table:rowMode>
              <table:columns>
                <table:Column>
                  <Text text="First Name" />
                  <table:template>
                    <Text text="{FirstName}" />
                  </table:template>
                </table:Column>
                <table:Column>
                  <Text text="Last Name" />
                  <table:template>
                    <Text text="{LastName}" />
                  </table:template>
                </table:Column>
              </table:columns>
            </table:Table>
          </VBox>
        </Page>
      </App>
    </mvc:View>`,
    models: {
      undefined: new ODataModel({
        serviceUrl: "https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/(S(w2saquxz0v41rmteqmgyytks))/",
        autoExpandSelect: true,
        sharedRequests: true,
      }),
      "viewModel": new JSONModel({ grow: true }),
    },
  });

  control.placeAt("content");
});
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://sdk.openui5.org/nightly/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.m,sap.ui.table,sap.ui.layout,sap.ui.unified"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-on-init="onUI5Init"
  data-sap-ui-compat-version="edge"
  data-sap-ui-exclude-jquery-compat="true"
  data-sap-ui-resource-roots='{ "my.demo": "./" }'
  data-sap-ui-xx-wait-for-theme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

<sup>Press <kbd>Run Code Snippet</kbd> and then "Full Page" to see the table adjusting its height automatically depending on the viewport height.</sup>

---

[API reference: `sap.ui.table.rowmodes.Auto`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.table.rowmodes.Auto)
[Understanding `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis`](https://css-tricks.com/understanding-flex-grow-flex-shrink-and-flex-basis/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example: [Table in nested boxes](https://plnkr.co/edit/UJz6J2D7zT0tXqe6)
I've also included `Text` element, so you may see how styling should be applied depending on how many child elements are for each box.

The main thing is that, while VBox/HBox is being created, by default it wraps UI controls inside another `div` element. Because of that, not only the Box element has to set it's height to 100%, but also the 'item' of this box element.

Other option is to change the property `renderType="Bare"` and than again work with styles. https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.FlexRendertype

P.S. sorry for my styling (still learning stackoverflow)

```
<mvc:View
   controllerName="sap.ui.sample.App"
   xmlns="sap.m"
   xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
   xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
   xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
   xmlns:table="sap.ui.table">
   <App>
      <Page>
         <content>
            <VBox class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin VBOX3">            
               <l:Splitter id="CSL_idSplitter" height="100%" resize="onSplitterResize">
                  <VBox class="VBox2">
                     <HBox justifyContent="SpaceBetween" class="HBox1">
                        <VBox class="VBOX1">
                           <table:Table 
                              id="idTable"
                              height="100%"
                              visibleRowCountMode="Auto"
                              fixedBottomRowCount="1"/>
                        </VBox>
                     </HBox>
                  </VBox>
               </l:Splitter>
               <Text text="Hello"/>            
            </VBox>
         </content>
      </Page>
   </App>
</mvc:View>

.VBOX3{
  height: 100% 
}

.VBOX3 div:first-of-type{
  height: 100% 
}

.VBox2{
    height:100%
}

.HBox1{
    height: 100%
}

.VBOX1{
  height: 100% 
}

.VBOX1 > div{
  height: 100% 
}
```

Comment: For me setting the height of the table in the xml to 100% I get this error:

Assertion failed: Element sap.ui.core.mvc.XMLView#__xmlview1--idChooseSpaceLayers: encountered unknown setting 'height' for class sap.ui.table.Table (value:'100%').

Thanks for the effort but I think the answer from BBoghyon with the renderType="Bare" (that you also mentioned) is more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `renderType="Bare"` to all the relevant FlexBoxes. From the API reference:

> #### [`renderType`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/9e86ae38a19c55bf53b13e347b14398ee8ec3b57/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/FlexBox.js#L106-L111)
>
> Determines whether the layout is rendered as a series of divs or as an unordered list (ul).
>
> We recommend to use `Bare` in most cases to avoid layout issues due to browser inconsistencies.

And

> #### [`Bare`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.FlexRendertype#properties)
>
> The UI5 controls are **not** wrapped in an additional HTML element.

I.e. the parent of the table should be the VBox element in 100% height without the div element in between.

Comment: Thanks, this almost worked. If you can update your anwer, I'll accept it.
When I added renderType="Bare" (only) to the direct-parent FlexBox (others aren't necessary) the style of the table said "height: auto". When I added a class with "height: 100%" to the table in the XML it worked!

Comment: @IceRevenge I just added another, probably the actual solution to the issue that doesn't require any custom CSS. Adding `renderType="Bare"` is always recommended and it does skip rendering the the intermediate `<div>`-element but that's not the issue.