# sap.ui.table.Table inside of Scroll Container: visibleRowCountMode=“Auto” not working

Tags: sapui5

This is a follow-up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66662597/sap-ui-table-table-visiblerowcountmode-auto-not-working-with-vbox-flexbox) question. Basically, I have the same problem as described there where the table does not have as many rows as possible, there is more space there but it is unused.

I got it working for my table with the help of the answers in the last question. Now I had to adda horizontal Scroll-Container (the height is fixed) arround this table. Then the problem came up again.
[image]

I built **a demo version** with which you can see the problem and try arround with [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/gUknH2nDjHU8RlCZ).

The wanted result is just like as if you removed the ScrollContainer, then the table fills the entire page.

The same problem occurs when using this table inside of an IconTabBar but I was able to find an ugly work-around which does not work here. After the table was rendered I added the style `height: 100%` manually to the html-parents of the table (these are generated divs of the IconTabBar). This enabled the Table to receive the full height from its parents. With the ScrollContainer this tactic does not seem to work.

Comment: What is the actual target design? According to the provided plunk (thx btw!), it looks like the text on the right-hand side is supposed to represent some helpful guide for the table. In that case, have you [considered using a **`DynamicSideContent`** instead](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/dynamic-side-content/)? IMHO going for a `ScrollContainer` is an unfortunate result of [xy-problem](https://xyproblem.info/) as the table already comes with a horizontal scrollbar and displays it if the width doesn't suffice. I'd suggest to look for another control to be more Fiori-aligned.

Comment: The text on the side was just there to test the problem. I have several tables with this problem. In one table it is a legend (a HBox with several color and text entries). In another table the problem is that the buttons in the toolbar are also moved to the right when the table columns are resized. Unfortunately, I am unable to reproduce this problem in the plunk and I am not quite sure why. The idea was to put the table in the ScrollContainer so that only the table moves but the buttons above and below stay fixed. I will try to add a demo again. I‘ll also add a picture to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the restrictions of visibleRowCountMode="Auto"
https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Table%23methods/getVisibleRowCountMode

See [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AybDBp6XaxXszq4g) the the layoutData definition for the HBox so that it gains the height from its parent

```
<layoutData>
    <FlexItemData growFactor="1" />
</layoutData>
```

and also height: 100% style for the ScrollContainer's inner element which also let the table know the height of its container.

Answer (score -1):

You can fix it like this:

```
onInit: function () {
    this.oTable = this.byId("TableID");
    this.oTable.onAfterRendering = function () {
      const table = this.getTable();
      const aColumns = table.getColumns();
      for (let i = 0; i < aColumns.length; i++) {
        aColumns[i].setProperty("width", "auto");
      }
      this.setHeight("100%");
    };
}
```

And you may try these properties:

```
flexible: true/false,
resizable: true/false,
autoResizable: true/false,
width : "auto"
```

Comment: Please don't rely on rendering APIs such as `onAfterRendering` in application development (Also do **not** overwrite it!!). There are almost always better options. But for that, we need more information from the question author.